# Jquery each only adds the first elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where i can select a product then set a begin week (for example 1) and a end week (for example 10)
Then i have a table with 52 rows that represent the weeks. I want when a user selects a product and set the weeks it adds the product in the table on the set weeks.
Everything works fine when i add week 1 - 10 but when i put 3 - 10 it doesnt work.

Here is my Jquery code

```
$(".sub_product_toevoegen").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product = $("select[name='select_product'] option:selected").val();
    var start_week = $("input[name='start_week']").val();
    var eind_week = $("input[name='eind_week']").val();

    $(".tabs .nieuwe_offerte_table tbody tr td a.product_toevoegen").each(function(index) {

        for (i = start_week; i <= eind_week; i++) {
            if (i == index + 1) {
                $(this).append(product);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Someone can tell me what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? If so, please post the error message and stack trace if available.

Comment: show html or giv jsfiddle

Comment: Can you include your HTML markup or a jsfiddle?

Comment: How about a better title to start with?

Comment: ...preferably all of the above

Comment: edited the title, working on jsfiddle

Comment: Noticing Downvoting in Gang :)

Comment: btw, where you use this: `$(".tabs .nieuwe_offerte_table tbody tr td a.product_toevoegen")`, you don't have to add all the element between the first and the target. This `$(".tabs .nieuwe_offerte_table a.product_toevoegen")` will suffice. (Maybe you can even leave the `.tabs` out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing famous each function to this:

```
$(".tabs .nieuwe_offerte_table tbody tr td a.product_toevoegen").slice(start_week-1, eind_week).append(product);
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Could you explain a bit what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Your each loop has loop `index` but you did not used it correct way. You should compare inside only `if (i == index + 1)`, but you added another `for` loop without reason. Saying `each` method will loop all the selected elements and while looping first parameter is `index`.

Comment: But then i is not defined ?